# Nested composite views in marionette

Tags: marionette, backbone-views

When dealing with Marionettes different views, is it possible to have a composite view calling another composite view calling an item view? For instance, the structure could be a list of objects, each object having a list of attributes:

```
ObjectList = Marionette.CompositeView.extend({
    template: "#objectlist-template",
    childView: Object,
    initialize: function(){
    }
});

Object = Marionette.CompositeView.extend({
    template: "#object-template",
    childView: Attribute
    initialize: function(){
    }
});

Attribute = Marionette.ItemView.extend({
    template: "#attribute-template",
});
```

I tried doing this in my project, but it doesn't seem to work:

```
var objectListView = new ObjectList({
   collection: objects
});
```

How should the objects collection be structured?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is totally possible, but you will need some extra wiring. I think it's generally not considered best practice to have a collection with models that have attributes that are another collection.
I don't completely know your use-case so I will assume your `attributes` are just an array of strings and not something more complex.

You should also refrain from using variable names like `Object`, `Attribute`, etc. as those clash with/are very close to reserved words. I renamed the views in my example.

So mainly, in your ItemView you need to create the collection using an attribute of your model:

```
var ItemListView = Marionette.CompositeView.extend({
    template  : "#objectlist-template",
    childView : ItemView
});

var ItemView = Marionette.CompositeView.extend({
    template   : "#object-template",
    childView  : ItemAttributeView
    initialize : function(){
        // Assuming 'itemAttributes' is something like ['red','yellow','green']
        var itemAttributes = this.model.get('itemAttributes');

        // Map itemAttributes to be objects to instantiate models
        // `name` can then be used in the attribute's template
        itemAttributes = _.map(itemAttributes, function(ia){ return { name : ia }; });

        // use this array to set the collection for this compositeview
        this.collection = new Backbone.Collection( itemAttributes );
    }
});

var ItemAttributeView = Marionette.ItemView.extend({
    template: "#attribute-template",
});
```